# How do I get filename completion to ignore a leading `=`?

Tags: autocompletion, filesystem

Occasionally, when writing shell scripts and such, I have entries of the form:

```
foo=/bar/baz
```

To get filename completion (`<C-x> <C-f>`) to work, I have to put a space after the `=`, and then remove it after completion. I don't have any filenames which contain `=`, so I don't care about it being part of the completion. How do I get it to work with the `=`? I use Linux primarily, but Windows on occasion too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The list of valid filename characters is given by the `isfname` variable. From [`:he 'isfname'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27isfname%27):

```
'isfname' 'isf'     string  (default for MS-DOS, Win32 and OS/2:
                         "@,48-57,/,\,.,-,_,+,,,#,$,%,{,},[,],:,@-@,!,~,="
                        for AMIGA: "@,48-57,/,.,-,_,+,,,$,:"
                        for VMS: "@,48-57,/,.,-,_,+,,,#,$,%,<,>,[,],:,;,~"
                        for OS/390: "@,240-249,/,.,-,_,+,,,#,$,%,~,="
                        otherwise: "@,48-57,/,.,-,_,+,,,#,$,%,~,=")
```

To make Vim ignore `=` as a filename character, remove `=` from this list:

```
:set isfname-==
```

Now, completion should work for `foo=/ba...`.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to enclose the filename in quotes:

```
foo="/bar/baz"
```

Then file completion (`<C-x> <C-f>`) works after the first `"`.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!