# How do I get filename completion to ignore a leading '/'?

Tags: autocompletion

In a Jekyll file I have

```
 <IMG SRC="/assets/images/
```

I would like to use the filename autocompletion shortcut to insert the rest of the filename, but this fails because of the leading slash.

When I remove the leading slash, the completion works perfectly but I then I have to put it back in for the code to work.

How can I tell vim to ignore the slash?

Related question is [this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/how-do-i-get-filename-completion-to-ignore-a-leading) but the solutions do not appear relevant.

Comment: Fwiw it’s not usually necessary to write jekyll links that way (one of the template params is site.url or something similar. You can also use `{% link file %}`, which works with relative paths!)

Comment: I don't think there's really any way to do this without overriding the `<C-x><C-f>` logic to implement your own, or using `completefunc`. See [How to create my own autocomplete function?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4584/51) The help page says *"Note: the 'path' option is not used here (yet)"*, so the "real solution" would probably be to implement that in Vim.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble - oooh, will check that out (although I still find the question interesting)

Answer (score 1):

I work around it by first typing the path without the leading slash '/',
so that vim will complete it, and then afterwards prepend the slash using one of the following maps

```
nnoremap [MAPKEYS] m'F"a/<Esc>`'l
imap [MAPKEYS] <Esc>[MAPKEYS]a
```

The cursors position is also restored. Note that the maps rely on the path being surrounded by quotes (`"the/path"`).

PS: remember to use `<buffer>` if you put this in an `ft` file (e.g. `.vim/after/ftplugin/{markdown,liquid}.vim` or in autocommands. A more robust version of the above is given here (put in `.vimrc` and reload):

```
augroup slash_bindings
  autocmd! slash_bindings
  autocmd Filetype markdown,liquid,yaml nnoremap <buffer> <MAPKEY> m':call search("['\"]", "b")<CR>a/<Esc>`'l
  autocmd Filetype markdown,liquid,yaml imap <buffer> <MAPKEY> <Esc><MAPKEY>a
augroup end
```